# Understanding (simple?) C++ Inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm struggling a bit to understand why this code snippet does not compile.

```
#include <cstdio>

class A {
public:
    virtual int potential()=0;
    virtual int potential(int arg, int arg2)=0;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    int potential() { return 1; }
    virtual int potential(int arg, int arg2) { return 2; }
};

class C : public B {
public:
    int potential(int arg, int arg2) { return 3; }
};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    C c;
    int value = c.potential();
    printf("Got %i\n", value);
    return 0;
}
```

I have two pure virtual methods, both named `potential` in the abstract superclass `A`. The subclass `B` then defines both, but a further subclass `C` only needs to redefine one of the methods.

However, on compilation, only the method defined in `C` is recognized, and `potential()` isn't seen (this should have been inherited from `B`):

```
In function 'int main(int, char**)':
Line 23: error: no matching function for call to 'C::potential()'
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

If I rename `A::potential(int, int)` to something else all the way down the inheritance tree, such as `A::somethingElse(int, int)`, then the code compiles fine, and the output is `Got 1`, as expected.

This has been verified using **clang**, **g++** and MSVC's **cl**.

Any ideas on what is going on?

Comment: Using `<cstdio>` as suggested.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> However, on compilation, only the method defined in C is recognized, and potential() isn't seen (this should have been inherited from B).

C++ doesn’t work like this: because you implemented a different `potential` method (a method of the same name but with different parameters) in `C`, the other method is *hidden* as far as `C` is concerned.

Hiding happens because of the way that C++ resolves (overloaded) method names: when you call a method `potential` on an instance of a class (here `c`), C++ searches in the class whether a method of that name exists. If that isn’t the case it continues its search in the base classes. It goes further up in the hierarchy until at least one method of that name is found.

But in your case, C++ doesn’t have to search far: the method already exists in `C`, so it stops its search. Now C++ tries to match the method signature. Unfortunately, the method signature doesn’t match but at this time it’s too late: overload resolution fails; C++ doesn’t search for other methods that might match.

There are three solutions:

1. Import it with `using` in C:

   ```
   class C : public B {
   public:
       using B::potential;
       int potential(int arg, int arg2) { return 3; }
   };
   ```
2. Call the method from a base class instance in `main`:

   ```
   C c;
   B& b = c;
   int value = b.potential();
   ```
3. Qualify the name explicitly in `main`:

   ```
   C c;
   int value = c.B::potential();
   ```

Comment: Interesting - I haven't seen the `using` keyword used like this, before. How come the other method is hidden? It has a different signature than the defined method, right?

Comment: @Dan: That's just the way inheritance is in C++. Call it a quirk if you like.

Comment: @Dan I’ve added an explanation of overload resolution and hiding.

Comment: That's why I love C++ =) the quirks never end.

Comment: Three really good alternatives to getting things to work. #3 was new to me too :) but I think I'll go with #1. If I had e.g. 3 different `potential` methods, and only 1 override, would the `using B::potential;` bring all methods from `B` into C's scope?

Comment: @Dan Yes, `using` brings all methods of that name into scope. And you’re right, this is usually the best alternative.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is name hiding.

Function overloads and function inheritance aren't best friends. Usually you **either** <sup>[hmm, what's "either" for three?]</sup>:

- Overload a function within a single class. Everything works fine.
- Inherit a non-overloaded function from a base class. Everything works fine.
- Re-implement a non-overloaded function from a base class `B` in a derived class `C`. `C::func` *hides* `B::func` because it has the same name.

You're using inheritance *and* overloading, and your `C::func` is hiding `B::func` *and every overload of it*, even the ones that aren't re-implemented in `C`.

It's a bit of a quirky confusion of C++, but it's easily resolved.

In short, the solution is to bring `B::potential()` into scope for `C` with the `using` statement:

```
class C : public B {
public:
    using B::potential; // brings overloads from B into scope
    int potential(int arg, int arg2) { return 3; }
};
```

I have written an article [here](http://kera.name/articles/2010/08/overcoming-name-shadowing-in-c/) that demonstrates the issue in depth.

Comment: You can use _either_ for three options, also :)

Comment: @Dan: That's not really how it works, but you'll get no moaning from me! Whether you got your answer is what counts.

Comment: @davka: I don't recognise "American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language" as an authority on English.

Comment: @Tomalak: touchee :) it supports your case, though